# Displaying Long URLs in Firebug

Tags: firebug

My web app creates some pretty long URLs that get shortened when they are viewed in Firebug. This is the same thing that is described here

[Shorten URL for display with beginning and end preserved (Firebug 'Net' panel style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903002/shorten-url-for-display-with-beginning-and-end-preserved-firebug-net-panel-st)

I was wondering if there is a nice way to make those URLs longer. You can see below some google URLs, the first is shortened, the second my mouse is hovering over. It would be nice to make the shortened URLs take up all the whitespace on the first line (esp since i have a big monitor so my window is often very wide)

[image: example of experience]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently (Firebug 2.0.1) [hardcoded to be cropped](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/962d82bd1d31171a39a57aa7f5b14da8e1d164a3/extension/content/firebug/net/spy.js#L963) when the URL is longer than 100 characters.

You may [file an enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry?template=User%20enhancement%20request) to allow to change that value.